# How to find values from div and input at the same time (as in a row) using find(), text(), val()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**SOLVED - various approaches, thx guys I learned again**

The HTML

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="c1">value1</div>
    <div class="c2">value2</div>
    <div class="c3><input type="number" value="3" class="i1" /></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="c1">value3</div>
    <div class="c2">value4</div>
    <div class="c3><input type="number" value="1" class="i1" /></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

I use this code extract the values (a slightly modified version of this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098934/build-json-to-send-to-php-using-a-for-loop-maybe))

```
var fields = [ 'c1', 'c2','i1'];

var data = [];

$('.container .row').each(function(i, tr) {
    var row = {};
    for (var f = 0; f < fields.length; ++f) {
        row[fields[f]] = $(tr).find('.' + fields[f]).text()
    }
    data.push(row);
    console.log(data);
});
```

This works perfect but not for all data

> c1 = value1
>
> c2 = value2
>
> i1 =
>
> ---
>
> c1 = value3
>
> c2 = value4
>
> i1 =

since `i1` is an input, `text()` will not work I would need `val()`, I want to know how I can get the value of `i1` and add it to `row[fields[f]]` so the final ouput is:

> (row 1)   c1 = value1
>
> c2 = value2
>
> i1 = 3
>
> ---
>
> (row 2)
>
> c1 = value3
>
> c2 = value4
>
> i1 = 1

1. Using `if/else` doesn't work it will do either one or the other
2. Adding another .find() breaks it
3. Using function(){} doesn't work.
4. Using append or appendTo doesn't work
5. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7826685/how-to-get-div-text-also-with-its-inputs-values/7826758#7826758) doesn't seem to work in this case

There must be a way to do this. Who can help me out?

Comment: I feel kind of stupid asking this, so don't bite my head off :)

I need the (data) values to eventually be send to a php file (preferably in jSON format. 

The steps: get the data > add it to a form (textarea field) > send it through $.post > in php use json_decode to get the data in an array and substract it from there

But I keep getting the data as an object and I still don't understand why that happens, I guess it's because jQuery wraps it in some sort of jQuery object. How can I bypass that?

Comment: you should ask a separate question (or better yet look for the ones already here) that ask about using JSON for POST data. The answers here should suffice for actually creating the original data, but the one thing you _shouldn't_ be doing is dropping that data back into the form for posting.

Comment: Great thx for the advice, I was in doubt wether to ask a new question or not. Chose the wrong path. And thx for the heads up on: NOT dropping the data into a form, it felt kinda weird doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works - demo at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/82Tep/

```
var fields = {
    c1: 'text',
    c2: 'text',
    i1: 'val'
};

var data = $('.container .row').map(function(row, tr) {
    var obj = {};
    $.each(fields, function(key, func) {
        obj[key] = $('.' + key, tr)[func]();
    })
    return obj;
}).get();
```

Earlier versions weren't right because I hadn't spotted that the OP wanted an object rather than an array for the inner dimension.

This approach has the advantage that you can call *other* jQuery functions on those elements without changing the actual code - just change the `fields` map to say which function you want to call.

Comment: i can't wait to see the fiddle :)

Comment: Little bit left for full automation :) It will be failing to stop with that. I see this awesome code with no types in `fields`.

Comment: @VisioN what if he wants the `.html()`?  In your code he'd have to have special code - in this you just change the `fields` table.

Comment: Oy this is a hard one, I'll have to read it over a few times, I didn't know the map() function.  Another nice one. Thx!

Comment: @Alnitak Well, sometimes extended flexibility may shoot in the leg :) Then for complete solution you have to check to existence of `func`.

Comment: @VisioN yup - in any event the real point of this answer is to demonstrate that you can actually make which jQuery _function_ to call a _variable_.

Comment: @Fluffy I've updated to use `jQuery.map` instead of `Array.prototype.map` - this'll make it more compatible with earlier browsers that don't have that latter function.

Comment: @Alnitak, thx, I thought I posted a reaction last night but I guess I didn't press 'Add'

Answer (score 2):

Try to add if clause for checking whether an element is of `input` type. If so, it will get value with `val()`, otherwise with `text()`.

```
for (var f = 0; f < fields.length; ++f) {
    var el = $(tr).find('.' + fields[f]);
    row[fields[f]] = el.is(":input") ? el.val() : el.text();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach is simply:

```
var fields = ['c1', 'c2', 'i1'];

var data = [];

$('.container .row').each(function(i, tr) {

    var row = {};
    for (var f = 0; f < fields.length; ++f) {
        row[fields[f]] = $(tr).find('.' + fields[f]).text() || $(tr).find('input.' + fields[f]).val();
    }
    data.push(row);
    console.log(data);
});​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/aAnDx/).

This approach assigns either the `text()` or, if there is no text, instead assigns the `val()` of the element of the particular class-name.

Comment: Great thank you! That did it Why is it always this simple? I've been trying for hours.  So all was needed was the || (or)

Comment: Pretty much, yeah; because there was nothing returned by the call to `text()` (since an text input doesn't have any 'text' content), it evaluated to a 'falsey' value, which caused the statement following the `||` (`OR`) to be evaluated.